# C#: Skip line in foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm writing a very simple script interpreter in C#.  There are no `If/Else` statements or user-programmable subroutines in this language; the only control-flow is the `goto` keyword.

If I'm using a `foreach` loop to parse the script line-by-line, how can I make the program "jump" to the line number specified by the parameter in the `GoTo()` block?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string testLines = "SomeCommand(34,32)\n" +
    "SomeCommand(1)\n" +
    "GoTo(5)\n" +
    "This(\"Will\",\"Be\",\"Skipped\")\n" +
    "Destination(\"OfTheGoToKeyWord\")";
    Regex r = new Regex("^(?<cmd>\\w+)[(](?<params>\\S+)[)]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    string[] lines = testLines.Split('\n');
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] matches = r.Split(line);
            if (matches[1].Equals("GoTo"))
            {
                GoToLineSpecifiedByMatchesElement2();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert `foreach` into a `for` loop and set loop index to the value of `GoTo`

Comment: Or alternatively you could use some ugly continue statements. Unless goto allows going back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string testLines = "SomeCommand(34,32)\n" +
                           "SomeCommand(1)\n" +
                           "GoTo(5)\n" +
                           "This(\"Will\",\"Be\",\"Skipped\")\n" +
                           "Destination(\"OfTheGoToKeyWord\")";
        Regex r = new Regex(
            "^(?<cmd>\\w+)[(](?<params>\\S+)[)]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

        List<string> lines = testLines.Split('\n').ToList();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < lines.Count)
        {
            try
            {
                var input = lines[i];
                var matches = r.Split(input);
                if (matches[1].Equals("GoTo"))
                {
                    i = testLines.IndexOf(input);
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah the `i++` should probably be need some extra care since you have a `try-catch`. But you can do the debugging & testing yourself :). You'll get the idea

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to use foreach for this. You'll want a `while` loop and jump by index.

It looks like this may just be the tip of the iceberg for what you want to do. If so, you'll quickly outgrow regular expressions. Read up on compiler design, specifically how to separate the lexical, syntactic, and semantic stages, and how to re-use existing tools that can help you at each step.

It also seems likely to me that after reading a few things you'll quickly understand why your current approach may not be enough, but also a full-blown compiler might be overkill. In that case, .Net has some nice features built in to help define what are called "[Domain Specific Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126278.aspx)" that may be just what you need.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, this is something I plan to pursue with more complex languages in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop. The variable `i` can keep track of your current line, and you can change it inside the loop, simulating the goto.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        string[] matches = r.Split(lines[i]);
        if (matches[1].Equals("GoTo"))
        {
            i = matches[2] - 1; // -1 because for loop will do i++
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think a while is better suited for this because a for loop kind of implies a specific number of itterations. A while can be made to increment only when needed